# One-Loop Fayet-Iliopoulos term in heterotic string

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry

I'm having problems computing the coefficient of the Fayet-Iliopoulos term, following the book of Kiritsis. With the term in the effective action in the Einstein Frame

> $$- \frac{\zeta}{2}M_s ^2 \int \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} B_{\mu \nu}F_{\rho \sigma}$$

to calculate $\zeta$ he computes the following correlator in the odd spin structure

> $$\epsilon^1 _{\mu \nu} \epsilon^2 _{\rho}  \langle B^{\mu \nu} A^\rho \rangle = \frac{\epsilon^1 _{\mu \nu} \epsilon^2 _{\rho}}{8 (2 \pi l_s)^4} \int_F \frac{d^2 \tau}{\tau_2^2} \int\frac{d^2 z}{\tau_2} \left\langle (\partial X^\mu + i p \cdot \psi \psi^\mu) \bar{\partial} X^\nu e^{2i p_1 \cdot X } \big|_z  \times \psi^\rho \bar{J} e^{2i p_2 \cdot X } \big|_0 \times \oint \frac{dw}{2 \pi i}\left(\frac{2i}{l_s^2}\psi^\rho \partial X^\rho + G^{int}\right)\big|_w\right\rangle $$

I can't really understand where the $8$ at the denominator comes from and the normalization of the vertex operators, and also why he puts the contour integral for the supercurrent. In addition he claims

> $$\mathrm{Tr}[(-1)^F \bar{J}]_R = -2 \pi \bar{\eta}^2 \mathrm{Tr}[Q]_\text{massless}$$

I don't understand how to derive this formula.
If someone that know or that already did the computation could help me.